# Babel module not being seen even though it is in package.json and installed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, webstorm

I need some help with my React project. I can't compile any JSX and I'm completely lost on what to do. Currently this is the error when trying to compile:

[image: Compile error]

I've tried deleting my package.json and `node_modules` folder and then running `npm install`. Nothing seems to work. I've tried completely removing node.js and everything relating to it and npm and reinstalling everything. I'm completely lost on what to do. I'm currently running WebStorm if that helps.

package.json:

```
   {
  "name": "tutorial",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint-config-react-app": "^7.0.1"
  }
}
```

I have a babel.config.js in the src directory:

```
module.exports = {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]

};
```

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Comment: Here is my babel.config.js file:

module.exports = {
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]

};

and my package.json dependencies:

"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.18.6",
    "eslint": "8.22.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5"
  },

Comment: Updated my original post

Comment: does it help if you move the babel config from the `scr` folder to the root directory?

Comment: No, moving the babel config to the root directory doesn't change anything.